# Socket.io and Express with nginx

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, socket.io

I'm struggling to configure nginx correctly to ensure that it can handle the proxy for both Express (port 8081) and Socket.io (port 3000). Here is my config that is currently yielding a 502 error for the whole request, not just Socket.io:

```
server {

        root /var/www/example.com/public/;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com;

        location /socket.io/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location / {
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

As far as I understand it, I need to ensure the Websocket used by Socket.io is upgraded to HTTP but this is where I'm struggling to grasp what I need to be doing. Presumably both Socket.io and Express need to be running on different ports and then need to proxy to nginx as per my configuration above.

If I disable the Express proxy and just use nginx to serve up files then my assets are served but obviously I need this to work with both Express and Socket.io.

Edit: I'm running nginx 1.14 but looking at a nginx blog post suggests I need at least 1.3...yet it looks a fair few years old already so not sure why the Ubuntu package manager is so outdated. I'm getting no configuration errors in but connection refused in error logs due to upstream.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: 1. Are you use [this example](https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Express), who allow work on 1 port? ~ 2. Do you need to provide support for old browsers? [Browsers released after 2013](https://caniuse.com/#search=websocket) supports Websocket natively, so do you need this heavy library?

Comment: Hey, I'm pretty sure my config is the same as point 1, there or thereabouts. I would prefer them on different ports. I'm a little late to start refactoring to use a Websocket but I'll try and find time in the future :)

Comment: I hope that these are two apps sharing the code (otherwise it makes medium sense...). And it seems to me that the syntax used by you is called to process other blocks as well. Did you [read this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms)? And I'm think, that you should use `location ^~ /socket.io/`

Comment: I ended up binding them both on the same port and that worked just fine :) I was overcomplicating matters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express and socket.io can be on the same port.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(http)

app.use(
  express.static(__dirname + '/client')
)

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('Socket Connected');
   socket.emit('message', 'Hello Socket');
   socket.on('message', function (msg) {
      console.log(msg);
   });
})

http.listen(8080, () => console.log('Server is running @ localhost:8080')) //port
```

I have never used nginx or served a nodejs app with a server other then through nodejs itself. I am assuming you have a web app that you are serve it through nginx?

To use a socket on a different port you would have to create another nodejs server via `http` then use [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to let them connect. Using cors(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) can be dangerous I have been told. The simplest and most safe thing to so is keep your app under one port(server).

Socket.io takes care of setting up the web-socket and upgrading the connection. If you need to handle that in your own way I would recommend something like [faye-websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/faye-websocket), but socket.io abstracts a lot of that.

You learn more about socket.io with nodejs http servers [here](https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Node-http-server).

On the client side or your web page like `index.html`...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.io Test</title>
    <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- HTML -->
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('message', function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        socket.emit('message', 'Back at you');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

to run this code make a new folder `socket.io_test` then inside create a file named `app.js` and another folder `client` with a file `index.html`.
Copy the first code snippet into `app.js` and the second into `index.html`. `cd` into the root folder and run `npm init -y` then `npm i -s express socket.io` and last `node app.js` and point your browser to `localhost:8080`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Marking as accepted answer as this is the conclusion I basically came to myself - don't bind them on different ports. Seems to be very little need.